# published node module can't use aliases

Tags: typescript, npm, node-modules, create-react-app

I have an app created with create-react-app and it's using react-app-rewired/react-scripts-ts. My tsconfig has:

```
baseUrl: "src",
paths: {
    "src/*": "./*"
}
```

In various files in this app, the paths resolve just fine:

```
import { MyComponent } from "src/components/MyComponent";
```

This app was published and then getting imported into another app, whose package.json has:

```
"my-custom-app": "^0.1.0"
```

However, the parent app breaks and says it can't find "src/components/MyComponent" in the child app. If I make the child app use relative paths instead. it works fine.

Is the configuration incorrect, or are absolute paths not allowed when creating npm modules?

There's a similar issue with local development, where it doesn't seem to load sass properly. My child app has the config-overrides.js:

```
const rewireSass = require("react-app-rewire-scss");
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    config = rewireSass(config, env);
    ...
}
```

If I copy this into the parent app, then it loads sass. I want the apps to be independent, but it looks like the configurations aren't getting loaded in the child app properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your *baseUrl* is already *src* and paths is *relative to src*. So you have to go up a folder, otherwise you're pointing to *src/src*:

```
"baseUrl": "src",
"paths": {
  "src/*": [ "../*" ],
},
```

Comment: Changing it to go up one folder still gives the same error in the parent app:
    Module not found: Can't resolve 'src/myFile'